# Irreducible polynomial on $\mathbb{Z}_2$-field

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I've found a theorem in the book "Linear Groups" (Dickson, 1901, p.16.): "In $\mathbb{Z}_2$, the degrees of the irreducible divisors of $x^{2^m}-x$ are divisors of $m$."

I've read the prove in this book but i don't understand the proof. Can anybody help me?

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What is the proof, and what parts of it do you not understand? We can't help you understand something when you haven't told us what it is you do not understand.

Comment: Here is the proof:https://archive.org/details/lineargroupswith00dickuoft

I'm not good at Group theory, and my language is not good enough to understand the proof too (and I don't know about Galois's Fields Theory so I don't understand even the symbol they used).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of the proof is the following.

Let $p$ be *any* prime, and $f = x^{p^{m}} - x \in \mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$.

Then the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a field $E$ with $p^{m}$ elements. For the degree we have $\lvert E : \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rvert = m$.

Let $g$ be a monic, irreducible divisor of $f$, of degree $k$. Since $E$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, the polynomial $g$ will have a root (actually, all of its roots) $\alpha \in E$.

Since $g$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$, $g$ will be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$. Hence $\lvert \mathbb{Z}_{p}[\alpha] : \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rvert = k$.

By the [multiplicativity formula for degrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension#The_multiplicativity_formula_for_degrees)
$$
m 
=
\lvert E : \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rvert
=
\lvert E : \mathbb{Z}_{p}[\alpha] \rvert \cdot \lvert \mathbb{Z}_{p}[\alpha] : \mathbb{Z}_{p} \rvert
=
\lvert E : \mathbb{Z}_{p}[\alpha] \rvert \cdot k,
$$
so that $k$ divides $m$.